# Installing APK keeps on loading

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android app development, am using an online platform to learn but I have been having serious issues with android studio(2.1.2). It was first giving me errors on gradle build then I created another project and the error didn't show in the new project but in the new project when I run the program in gets to the launching app stage then it keeps on loading installing apk. What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide more detail..are you installing in emulator or android device?

Answer (score 0):

I already have the same issue before.

In your gradle.properties you can enlarge the heap with this property : `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M`(2048 = 2Go RAM allocated for Gradle).

In order to know if it's Android Studio issue or adb issue, you can try to install the APK by adb commands like : *adb install name.apk*.

You can write this command via Android Studio's terminal.